# What's the difference between using an -O flag and turning on the constituent optimizations individually?

Tags: c++, g++

I have a program which compiles and runs properly when no `-O` flags are set.

When I try building with `-Og`, the program complains of a pure virtual function being called and crashes.

I was trying to track this down, so I used the command

```
g++ -Og  -Q --help=optimizers
```

to get a list of optimizations that `-Og` turns on.  This gave me a list of 83 different optimization flags that are supposedly enabled. (Curiously, I still get 58 optimizations if I supply `-O0` instead of `-Og`.)

I tried building with this list of optimizations instead of `-Og` directly, with the idea that I'd use a binary search to find the offending optimizations.  To my surprise, what happened instead was that the program functioned correctly!

**Question**: Am I doing something wrong when I'm getting the list of enabled optimizations?  Or does the `-Og` flag have other effects?

---

**Bonus details**

Unfortunately I haven't been able to strip the program I'm compiling down to a minimal working example.  Whatever this is seems fairly delicate, and the problem goes away if, for instance, I add a `cout` inside of a constructor.  However, to give a basic sketch of what's going on here:

- There's a base class with a pure virtual method.
- The base-class constructor calls `std::bind(&Base::virtual_method, this)` and provides this as a callback to another object.
- The derived class implements the virtual method.
- The derived class constructor has some member initializers but no code in the constructor body.
- If I put code in the constructor body that can't be optimized out, e.g. a `cout`, then everything works as expected.

So I'm guess the part of the derived class constructor that populates the vtable pointer is being optimized out for some reason.  (I haven't manually checked the generated assembly because I haven't figured out how to do it yet.)

Comment: That's a strong sign you introduced _undefined behavior_ at some point in your program. Static analysis sometimes helps to detect such issues, if compiling with all warnings on gives you no hint.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No warnings with `-Wall -Wextra` turned on.  Can you recommend a static analysis tool?

Comment: _The base-class constructor calls `std::bind(&Base::virtual_method, this)`_ - is that legal (inside the base class constructor)?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Coverity is a fairly good SCA tool for c++.